# DokuWiki clicking on link displays FORBIDDEN page

Tags: acl, dokuwiki

I have searched the Forums and elsewhere for an answer... I'll keep researching but hoping that someone has run into this before...

I am using the latest download version of the “Closed” DokuWiki.  I am building a Knowledgebase of forms and processes.  I created a Start page and Menu page for *all* users to view, anything beyond that requires a login.

As admin, I can see all images and have access to all links.  Click the link, the forms displays perfectly.  (So no issue with capital letters or spaces).

However, when I login as a User, I can access all of the pages and see all of the text, but when I click on a link, the same Form as admin, instead of the form displaying in a new page, a new page is displayed with the word “Forbidden”.

So, I'm fairly sure it's an ACL issue.  For example, I have the page “Office Administration” available to all Users.  Do I need to somehow create a namespace or new page for all of the links, then give permission again?  I was hoping that by making the page accessible to all users, this would also allow them the click on all of the links on that page as well??

How do I make the links accessible to all users?  Image links are displayed to admin only.  Not even registered users can view the images... text is fine... images show as broken links.

Appreciate any help you can offer!  I have only been using DokuWiki for a couple of weeks but I am very happy with the results for far!

[image: ACL screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It was definitely an ACL (Access Control List) issue... so many settings...
I changed the Root* access to Upload and set the Start and Menu pages to Read only.  From here on out it's setting permissions per user.  whoo-hoo!